# SQL Server 2016 to configure the debugger?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2016

Faced with this problem,the debugger is not running SQL Server, can anyone set up the debugger? share your experience says that

> **failed to start debugging t-sql**

Answer (score 0):

TechNet talks about correcting port settings and user rights to get things going

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645997%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Does this help, or are you using Visual Studio's debugging capabilities?